# selecting deep elements in d3

Tags: html, css, dom, d3.js

So for my question you can refer to udacity.com main page.

Im trying to access this text -"The Udacity Difference" somewhere on the middle of the page.
I tried this :

```
d3.select("div.banner-content.h2.h-slim")
d3.select("div.banner-content.h-slim")
```

None of the above is working. So I tried looking in dev-tools element section for this page.
Then I could hover and see that :
div.banner-content has further

```
{div.container
      {div.row
          {div.col-xs-12 text-center
              {h2.h-slim}}}}
```

Then I thought ok I shoud try if I can get the "container" atleast, but then even this

```
d3.select("div.banner-content.div.container")
```

OR

```
d3.select("div.banner-content.container")
```

doesnt work !!!!

Wheres the fault in logic ?

Comment: I don't think that you can uniquely select this element in this case as there are no IDs, only classes that are also applied to other elements.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks but did you check the webpage. Is this possible that D3 wont be able to access such "ID-LESS" deep elements like this?

Comment: Oh it will be able to access the elements, I'm saying that it looks to me like there's no selector that will return *just* the element you're interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find nested elements using d3's chained syntax as shown below.

HTML:

```
 <div class="banner-content">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="h-slim">Header</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
d3.select("div.banner-content").select("div.container").select("h2.h-slim")
```

EDIT: No need to type such long syntax. Just need to separate the selectors using a space.

```
d3.select("div.banner-content div.container h2.h-slim")
```

Code below will also give you the same results in this case. You can specifically add tags if necessary.

```
d3.select("div.banner-content .container .h-slim")
```

Comment: that worked :-), but do I always need to type such long syntax to access such deep elements ? Or is there a shortcut logic for this

Comment: @Gilsha that was awesome, thanks for keeping both the syntaxes and explaining the differences between both. That helped in my case too